# MacOS: SquirrelSQL will not run from launchpad

Tags: java, macos, squirrel-sql

I installed jenv, OpenJDK, and SquirrelSQL on MacOS 13.

I am able to run SquirrelSQL from the terminal, but it would not run from launchpad: the icon gets displayed in the dock, bounces once, and then nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to symlink the JDK into the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines directory, so the system could not find a Java installation.  It worked from the shell because I set the path.

This fixed it:
`sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`